# Is it possible to use a thirdparty component that was written for AngularJS to be used in Angular2+ without conversion?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a third party component that was written using AngularJS, we are converting the application to Angular2+ but that component that was written in AngularJS is essential and it is a huge component. Is it possible to import both AngularJS and the third party component to be used in the new Angular2+ code? Would anyone know any options that I can use? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Which third party component are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at [ngUpgrade](https://github.com/angular/ngMigration-Forum/wiki/ngUpgrade).

*"One of the primary tools provided by ngUpgrade is called the UpgradeModule. This is a module that contains utilities for bootstrapping and managing hybrid applications that support both Angular and AngularJS code."*

Also - there are good references online for integrating AngularJS into Angular projects while you're working on a proper migration strategy. You can search for 'running AngularJS and Angular together' and find case studies that describe in detail the process of integrating an AngularJS project into a newer Angular one.